# Error on swing aplication when adding a foreign key through combo box

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox, dao

I am having a problem on an aplication that is suposed to save a carrer on a table trough a swing form, but i keep getting this error that says that I can not add to a child row, and I know that it can be caused by the value added to the child row not existing where the PK should go, but I know for certain that there is a PK of that value at the parent table, so I do not know what could be happening.
The value that I am sending to the FK is the index of a combo box

These are the two tables:

```
create table facultad(
        codigoFacultad int primary key auto_increment,
        nombre varchar(50),
        telefono varchar(50)
        );

create table carrera(
        codigoCarrera int primary key auto_increment,
        nombre varchar(50),
        cantidadMaterias int,
        codigoFacultad int,
        foreign key (codigoFacultad) references facultad(codigoFacultad) on update cascade
        );
```

This is the procedure that i am using to save on the database

```
create procedure insertarCarrera(in idCar int, nom nvarchar(75), numMater int, codFac int)
insert into carrera values(idCar, nom, numMater,codFac);
```

this is how i run the save from swing:

```
public void insertarCarrera(Carrera ca){

        try 
        {
            this.conectar();

            CallableStatement cal = this.getCon().prepareCall("{call insertarCarrera(?,?,?,?)}");

            cal.setInt(1, ca.getCodigoCarrera());
            cal.setString(2, ca.getNombre());
            cal.setInt(3, ca.getCantidadMaterias());
            cal.setInt(4, ca.getCodigoCarrera());
            cal.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exito al insertar ");

        } catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al insertar "+e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            this.desconectar();
        }
    }
```

conectar() is the method that calls the mySQL connection and ca is the object that i am filling with the data

and finaly this is how the data is being collected from the form

```
private void agregarCarrera() {

    ca.setCodigoCarrera(Integer.parseInt(this.jTxtCodigo.getText()));
    ca.setNombre(this.jTxtNombre.getText());
    ca.setCantidadMaterias(Integer.parseInt(this.jSpinMaterias.getValue().toString() ));
    ca.setCodigoFacultad(jCmbFacultad.getSelectedIndex());

    dCa.insertarCarrera(ca);
}
```

hope somebody can help, been strugling the whole day due to this

Comment: `been strugling the whole day due to this` - well what have you done to debug this? Did you first try getting your SQL statement working by hardcoding the data? Once this works, then you try getting the data from the form. Then you add debug statements to make sure the data you get from the form is the data you expect to get. You need to isolate where the error is occurring before we can help.

Comment: hi, yes i have tried inserting on the table directly through mysql workbench and it works fine, also i have been checking on the data at each point of the insertion and it sends the right value, si it has to do with the database. as for the error it is mysql error 1052 MYSQL Integrity Constraint Violation Exception

Comment: `i have tried inserting on the table directly through mysql workbench` - that is not what I asked. I asked if you used Java to add hardcoded data to the database. This sounds like an SQL problem not a Swing problem. If you can get the SQL working with hardcoded data in a Java program, then getting the data form the Swing form is a simple step. I'm don't know much about SQL. So my suggestion is to write a simple Java class that updates the table with hardcoded data. Then if you have a problem you can post the entire class in the "SQL" forum for the SQL experts to look at.

Comment: Include the exact SQL error message in the question. That may mean something to people who know SQL.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will get to it right now